# Google INDEED crawls ajax?

Tags: seo, google, javascript, web-crawlers, ajax

I don't understand how this didn't make a bigger BOOM online.

It is well known in the industry that google does not index AJAX (just google-search "google crawls ajax") and see dozens of articles stating that google does not crawl ajax by default.

There's a whole [Google AJAX Crawling Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more) thing going on, if you want to help google crawl your AJAX based content (by creating mirror pages for the search engine).

But 4 days ago, **[this technique had been deprecated](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.il/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html)**.

Now, in their blog post about it Google explains that

> Back then, our systems were not able to render and understand pages that use JavaScript to present content to users. [...] Times have changed. Today, as long as you're not blocking Googlebot from crawling your JavaScript or CSS files, we are generally able to render and understand your web pages like modern browsers.

(googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html)

This is BIG and I don't see it getting attention online.

This is also a big f**k-up for me personally.

A couple of years ago I started using AJAX for loading user comments on my website, knowing that google does not crawl ajax.

Now I looked at a couple of my website's pages that are seemingly banned, or over-looked by Google.

And to my surprise, lots of these exact pages contain bad quality content (keyword stuffing etc.) within the comments.

**How can one know if his AJAX based content is being crawled?**

Using the "Fetch as Google" tool will NOT show the AJAX based content. Also, google-searching for exact phrases that appear in the AJAX based content does not return results.

The whole subject is very confusing.

Comment: Not exactly sure what your question is here, anyway. One second your talking about google and ajax and then you talk about your site having bad content. There's no real question here.

Comment: No, the bad content is withing the ajax based content. Which according to everyone - is not supposed to be crawled by Google!

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate of a question from 2010. Times have changed. This is the whole point. @JohnConde

Comment: Made my question clearer. @JohnConde

Comment: `Times have changed` ~ answers can be improved and new answers can be added, there's never any need to create a new question. Questions can gain attraction through quality improvements via editing, and users can run bounty's to gain even better answers, more up to date and so on.

Comment: Previous questions are already marked as answered because they were answered correctly for that time... The questions themselves don't hold all of the data we have now. @SimonHayter

Comment: I think that this question can be relevant for many webmasters

Comment: `Previous questions are already marked as answered` Not relevant, new answers can be added at any time and the community can up vote these answers, its not uncommon to see unaccepted answers being out voted by the communities on a wide range of stacks. Accepting an answer is only for the person asking, not necessary people viewing the page. A question can have several answers too, some may not be apply to all people etc, while some may... etc.

Comment: This wouldn't be an issue if you had the necessary rep to run the bounty on that question to gain new or improved answers. My advice, stick around, help others and then if its still important to you run a bounty on it, as I said, no need to ask the same question just because its been 5 years or more.

Comment: OK @SimonHayter